# Why did my DoS attack fail against Windows 10?

Tags: windows, denial-of-service, windows-10

I have multiple devices - a Samsung and a Lenovo tab, an Amazon Alexa, an HP laptop running Windows 7, and another running Windows 10. Bored, I tried to DoS my Windows 10 laptop using my Windows 7 laptop. I did it using a batch file with the ping command, like so:

```
:loop
ping 192.168.0.1 -l 65500 -w 100 -n 1
goto :loop
```

A very primitive and basic way of trying it indeed. So I open about 30 command prompts running the same batch file all at once. This method worked quite well for my TP-Link router and other devices mentioned above, except for my Windows 10 laptop. It seems to have some sort of protection against the attack. It was quite literally unaffected.

Note that I was on the same network and did it using my Windows 7 laptop, and attacking the router cut off internet access for all other devices on the network as well.

Why exactly did this work on other devices, and not specifically on Windows 10?

What firewall rules and other mitigation measures does Windows 10 have in the above example that rendered it virtually immune to this simple yet effective DoS?

Comment: You're sending about 300 packets per second and 65kB per packet. That's 20MB/second. That's not a huge amount of traffic. Medium-fast internet can go faster than that. Copying a file from one computer to another definitely goes faster than that.

Answer (score 5):

You assume that it's a software difference that enabled the Win10 box to survive. But the devices that fell have ***much*** reduced hardware. You likely just flooded the CPU/memory of the IoT devices and tablets. They are not designed for even small levels of direct traffic to them. A Windows laptop is.

When playing with *network traffic* you need to run packet captures to gain insight. Otherwise, you're just guessing in the dark.

Comment: Thanks!, so that's what it was all - hardware?

Comment: I have no idea. My point is that you jumped to the conclusion that it was something specific to Windows 10. I'm saying that there are a lot of factors to consider. The most obvious being hardware that isn't designed to accept incoming traffic.

Comment: Isn't a router designed to accept and handle traffic?

Comment: @nobody yes, but most routers still have pretty minimal hardware, and they need the hardware resources to process that network traffic just like anything else.  This makes them more vulnerable to DoS.  This "fancy" netgear router: https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/R7000.aspx has a dual core 1GHZ processor with 256MB of RAM.  Compare that with, say, an iPhone, and the difference is quite striking.

Comment: @nobody home routers aren't typically designed to handle traffic **to it** on the LAN-side.

Comment: @ConorMancone that sounds beefy enough to handle 20MB/s of pings, but maybe the asker has an older router.

Comment: @user253751 That's one of the beefier Netgear routers.  However the point is more that that is still far less hardware than a typical home PC.  Therefore the result the OP is seeing (PC is fine but router isn't) is plausible, even if the exact details are uncertain.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the router has a chip which processes packets - the router's CPU does *not* have to deal with packets that aren't addressed to the router.